# using Eval in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, eval

hiii everyone....

i have small problem with my code in vb.net that i want to use (Eval) in my project

so i write this code :

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
 Text='<%#Eval("PAG_PAGES") == null ? "" : ((PostAgenciesModel.PAG_PAGES)(Eval("PAG_PAGES"))).PAGE_TITLE_AR %>' />
```

and this code i used in my C# project .... all want to show the (Label1) in inside my GridView....

`("PAG_PAGES")` is the name of table..

`PostAgenciesModel` is the `edmx`...

`PAGE_TITLE_AR` is the colum in `("PAG_PAGES")` that i want to show it

can anyone help plzzz

thanxx

Comment: Please don't forget about spelling and orthography

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using C# features in a VB.NET web application.

The `null` keyword and the `?:` and `==` operators are C# constructs

In VB.NET, `null` is `Nothing`, `==` is `IS` and `?:` is the [`IIf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d.aspx) function.

Comment: thanx for ur answer Oded ....but still i have problem ..

when i chang the code that u put it its give this Error :

Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'PAGE_TITLE_AR' is not a member of 'Char'.

i wrote my code like this :

`<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
                         Text='<%#Eval("Pages") is Nothing  IIf  ((ReportsOfficesModel.Pages)(Eval("Pages"))).PAGE_TITLE_AR %>'></asp:Label>`

Comment: The `IIf` function is not suitable here, since it always evaluates both the True and the False clause. Thus, accessing `Eval("PAG_PAGES")`'s member will result in a NullReferenceException, if `Eval("PAG_PAGES")` is Nothing. The `If` operator solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%# If(Eval("PAG_PAGES") Is Nothing, 
        "", 
        DirectCast(Eval("PAG_PAGES"), PostAgenciesModel.PAG_PAGES).PAGE_TITLE_AR) %>
```

Elaborating on what Oded wrote:

```
expr == null  --->  expr Is Nothing
a ? b : c     --->  If(a, b, c)
(Type)expr    --->  DirectCast(expr, Type)
```

Comment: hii....thanx for the answers guys.....

but still i have problem ...the messege erroe shows : 

' BC30007: Reference required to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' containing the base class 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject'. Add one to your project.'

i do add refernce in my project 'System.Data.Entity' but i don't know what is the problem

Comment: @Bin: This is a different problem (related to the entity framework, not to C# -> VB.NET); you should open a second question for that (and tag it with `entity-framework`).